# Converting DataFrame values to int, adding them and create new column with result?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe of string numbers, something like for example:

```
a,b,c
"1","2","3"
"4","5","6"
"7","8","9"
```

And I want to create a new column `d` with the addition of `a + c` so the end result would be:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
4,5,6,10
7,8,9,16
```

I'm still trying to convert just the columns of `a + c` to strings, but I have no idea how I'll add them together and create a new column of the result. Please help with this last problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion `read_csv` convert columns to integers.

So use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['d'] = df['a'] + df['c']
```

But if failed, then try convert to integer or floats:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['d'] = df['a'].astype(int) + df['c'].astype(int)
#floats 
#df['d'] = df['a'].astype(float) + df['c'].astype(float)
```

If there are also some strings between numeric is possible convert problems values to `NaN`s and sum:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df['d'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce') + pd.to_numeric(df['c'],  errors='coerce')
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you so much!

What if I wanted to operate with the data using another values? Like, say if I want column D to be the values of column A times 5.

Comment: @JorgeGill Then use `df['d'] = (df['a'] + df['c']) * 5` or `df['d'] = df['a'] + df['c'] * 5` - if need multiple by sum or by column `b`